# Simplify $x(t)=\exp{(-m\cdot t)}\cdot (a\cdot cos(k\cdot t) + b\cdot sin(k\cdot t)) = A\cdot \exp{(-m\cdot t)}\cdot cos(k\cdot t + c)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Simplification: $x(t)=\exp{(-m\cdot t)}\cdot (a\cdot cos(k\cdot t) + b\cdot sin(k\cdot t)) = A\cdot \exp{(-m\cdot t)}\cdot cos(k\cdot t + c)$.

There is no further explanation in the script, but I found this theorem: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicAdditionTheorem.html

So I thought $A=sgn(a)\cdot \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and  $c = - \arctan{b/a}$... but as far as I know :  $ \forall y \in \mathbb{R}:\arctan{y}\in \cup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} ((2n+1)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2},(2n+3)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2})  $

...while in my script it states: $-\pi \leq c < \pi$.

So what has been used to simplify the equation?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can go by.

We can say $A = \text {sgn(a)}\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$ in wich case, $c\in (-\frac {\pi}{2}, \frac {\pi}{2}]$

Or we can say $A = \sqrt {a^2+b^2}$ in wich case the sign of $a$ will influence $c$

Many calculators and computers have a function $\text {atan2(a,b)}$ which takes a two variable input an returns and output in $(-\pi,\pi]$

Answer (score 0):

To hold the equality, it is required that $$\tan c =-\frac ba \implies c =\tan^{-1} \left(- \frac ba\right) + n\pi$$ Since $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le \tan^{-1} \left(-\frac ba\right) \le \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have that $$-\frac{\pi}{2} +n\pi \le c \le \frac{\pi}{2} +n\pi$$

For simplicity, we take $n=0$ and so $$ -\frac{\pi}{2} \lt c \lt \frac{\pi}{2} \implies -\pi \le c \lt \pi$$

Note that the implication follows as $ (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})\subset [-\pi,\pi) $.

Comment: I don't see why $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le \tan^{-1} \left(-\frac ba\right) \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ could be, because $\tan^{-1} \left(-\frac ba\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ is always false since $\lim\limits_{x\to \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\tan (x) = \infty $. 

I think $c=\tan^{-1} \left(-\frac ba\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ is not possible, so why should one use "$\leq$"-sign instead of "$<$" ?

$c \in [-\pi,\frac{-\pi}{2})\cup (\frac{-\pi}{2},\pi]$ would make sense to me.

Comment: @CherryBlossom1878 The range of $\tan^{-1} x$ is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. $c$ could very well be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ if $a=0$. Besides, what’s the harm in making the inequality more flexible?

Comment: "what’s the harm in making the inequality more flexible?" It reduces the information value if one believes that $c=\tan^{-1} \left(-\frac ba\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ is not possible. You cannot divide by zero, so for "$a=0$"  $c$ is not defined as far as I know. Of course you could calculate $x(t)=\exp{(-m\cdot t)}\cdot (a\cdot cos(k\cdot t) + b\cdot sin(k\cdot t))$ for $a=0$ but this case is not so interessting.

Comment: If you define $ b/0 := \infty  $ then $\tan^{-1} y = \frac{\pi}{2}$ could be, but I'm not sure if that is allowed. Maybe you can justify it because $\lim\limits_{y\to\infty} \tan^{-1} (y)= \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @CherryBlossom1878 I’m only justifying your  script.  It reduces the information but it is still **valid**. Also, if we follow your argument then the range of arctan x shouldn’t actually include $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$? Do you believe $\tan\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac 10$ is undefined? It’s important to note we always talk about the limit, because nothing can ever equal $\infty$.

Comment: I think $\tan\frac{\pi}{2} = \frac 10$ is undefined and the range of arctan(y) doesn't include  $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. 

What I would understand is, that if one wants to allow the phase shift $\frac{\pi}{2} $ in the simplified equation of $ x(t)$ then we could just take $c=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$  as a special case for $a=0$ that can't be calculated with the $arctan$-function.

Comment: I did this calculation as an example to show that my definition is coherent with the original $x(t)$. If I set $c:=- sgn(b)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $a=0$ then I get for $b<0$:
$x(t)= A\cdot \exp{(-m\cdot t)}\cdot cos(k\cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2})  \\= A\cdot \exp{(-m\cdot t)}\cdot (-sin(k\cdot t ))  \\ =- A\cdot \exp{(-m\cdot t)}\cdot sin(k\cdot t )  \stackrel{(-A=b)}{=} \exp{(-m\cdot t)}\cdot b\cdot sin(k\cdot t )   $

Comment: @CherryBlossom1878 Yes, I had mixed up the range of arctan with that of arcsin. The range of $c$ would indeed be $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and taking $c=\frac{\pi}{2}$ implies $a=0$.